# How to add src folder to React-native and import absolutely?

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

I am trying to add `src` directory so that I would have something like

```
- package.json
- android
- ios
- src
   - foo
     - hello.js
- index.js
- App.js
- node_modules
```

Then I added

`watchFolders: [path.join(__dirname, 'src')],`

to `metro.config.js`

hoping to be able to do `import hello from 'foo/hello'` from anywhere (for example from `App.js`)

I also found that you could achieve the `absolute import` if you add folders under `node_modules`

```
- package.json
- android
- ios
- node_modules
   - foo
     - hello.js
- index.js
- App.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `package.json` inside the `src` folder with the following content

```
{
    "name": "src"
}
```

Then you can reference other files as such
`import hello from 'src/foo/hello'`

You can also check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xey5oBOX20s&t=55s)

Answer (score -2):

you need to create an index.js file to the foo folder

index.js

```
 import hello from './hello.js'

    export{
      hello
    }
```

where ever you want to import the file to

otherfile.js

```
import hello from '../../src/foo'
```